# Is there a way to install certificates to LocalMachine store without logging into windows?

Tags: windows-10, ssl, certificate

As a part of some dev work I was doing, I was trying to identify and document only the essential certificates required to run an app locally. Since I had a bunch of certs in my LocalMachine store, I thought I would export all the certs for backup, then delete them temporarily from the cert store, run the app locally and install certs as app complains about it. After running the app successfully, I would then install all from the backup.

The problem is I backed up certs that were installed and installed a few that my app complained about.. then I left for lunch, my device logged me out, and now when I try to log back in, I can’t log in to my device. After going insane about how a windows log in would stop working just like that, I have a theory. One of those certs I removed from LocalMachine store, it must have been used for windows log in. Is there anyway to install a cert to LocalMachine store without logging into windows?

The machine that I am locked out of is Win10 running as hyperv vm.

Comment: Contact your It Administrator. I suspect you are correct you removed a certificate required to log into your network.

Comment: When you can not log in because of the missing cert , & you are trying to install that cert ( without logging in ) such that you will be able to log in : Imagine some body else ( eg XXX ) doing the same , that is , install some other cert without logging in & then XXX can log in. This is a Security Issue ( it will be a huge Security "loop-hole" if somebody else can do it ) & hence it is generally not Possible. The "Correct Way" is to ask the "Admin" to log in & copy the cert. Alternately, if you have a snapshot of the vm ( taken before uninstalling the cert ) then you can try restoring that.